# Kubernetes on GCP - Getting message "Does not have minimum availability"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed the images of microservices currency-conversion and currency-exchange on Google cloud but in the Kubernetes Engine, I see that the pods/replica sets are not available.

When I check under Workload tab, I see that the service shows a message "Does not have minimum availability"

[image]

[image]

I added additional availability zone to increase the resources but that did not help.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Could you share the logs from your pods, the status of your nodes? You can use the following commands to get them:


```kubectl describe pod YOURPOD_NAME```

```kubectl get nodes```

Also could you please share the amount of resources (CPU and Memory) configured to your pod and which of these values are configured in your deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many reasons could be there behind failure:

- Low Resources so POD are not starting or pending
- Liveness or Readiness failing for PODs
- Configmap or secret which POD require to start is not available

You can describe the POD or check the logs of POD to debug more issue

```
kubectl describe pod <POD name> -n <Namespace name>
```

Answer (score 1):

The pod is crashing hence why you're getting "Does not mean minimum availability"

You should look at the logs of the container first and see why its crashing

`kubectl logs -n default {name of pod}`